# get an element from a subset of a matrix in Rarmadillo

Tags: r, rcpp, armadillo

I have a large-ish matrix.  I'm trying to sample from it with dynamically changing weights. As it's forced to use loops in R, I'm trying to implement it in Rcpp so it has the chance of running a bit faster.  After a bit of experimenting, I think I've figured out how to grab an index at random with the correct weights.

The trick is that I'm only sampling from a subset of columns at any given time (this can change to rows if it's more efficient in C - the matrix is actually symmetric).  My indices are only defined for this subset of columns.  In R, I'd do something along the lines of

```
large_matrix[, columns_of_interest][index]
```

and this works fine.  How would I do the equivalent using Rcpp/Armadillo?  My guess of

```
cppFunction("arma::vec element_from_subset(arma::mat D, arma::uvec i, arma::uvec columns) {
  # arma::mat D_subset = D.cols(columns);
  return D.cols(columns).elem(i);

  }", depends = "RcppArmadillo")
```

fails to compile (and `.at` instead of `.elem` doesn't work either, nor does the standard R trick of surrounding things in paranthesis.

This does work, but is what I'm trying to avoid:

```
cppFunction("arma::vec element_from_subset(arma::mat D, arma::uvec i, arma::uvec columns) {
  arma::mat D_subset = D.cols(columns);
  return D_subset.elem(i);

  }", depends = "RcppArmadillo")
```

Is there any way to accommplish this without needing to save `D.cols(columns)`?

Comment: We have a few articles on subsetting over at the [Rcpp Gallery](http://gallery.rcpp.org) including [this one on Armadillo subsetting](http://gallery.rcpp.org/articles/armadillo-subsetting/).  Maybe those can help you get started?

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel, I read through the Armadillo subsetting article before I posted - that helped immensely in setting up my weight function.  However, I didn't see any examples of extracting an element from the subset of a matrix.  (or a subset of a subset, etc. - anything that I could adapt directly).  I'm looking at the Rcpp gallery now, but my simple search of "subset" didn't look too promising.  I'll keep looking though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: No.

But, the problem is phrased incorrectly. Think about what is happening here:

```
(M <- matrix(1:9, 3, 3)) 
#>      [,1] [,2] [,3]
#> [1,]    1    4    7
#> [2,]    2    5    8
#> [3,]    3    6    9

columns_of_interest = 1:2
M[, columns_of_interest] 
#>      [,1] [,2]
#> [1,]    1    4
#> [2,]    2    5
#> [3,]    3    6
```

From here, if we have the `index` being 1, then we get:

```
index = 1
M[, columns_of_interest][index]
#> 1
```

So, in essence, what's really happening is an entry-wise subset of [`(i,j)`](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#element_access). Thus, you should just use:

```
Rcpp::cppFunction("double element_from_subset(arma::mat D, int i, int j) { 
                  return D(i, j);
                  }", depends = "RcppArmadillo")
element_from_subset(M, 0, 0)
#> [1] 1
```

I say this based on the *R* and *C++* code posted, e.g. *R* gives 1 value and *C++* has a return type permitting only one value.

---

The code posted by OP is shown without the error. The initial error as compiled will indicate there is an issue using an `Rcpp` object inside of an `arma` class. If we correct the types, e.g. replacing `Rcpp::IntegerVector` with an `arma` appropriate type of either `arma::ivec` or `arma::uvec`, then compiling yields a more informative error message.

Corrected Code:

```
Rcpp::cppFunction("double element_from_subset(arma::mat D, int i, arma::uvec columns) { 
  return D.cols(columns).elem(i);
  }", depends = "RcppArmadillo")
```

Error Message:

```
file6cf4cef8267.cpp:10:26: error: no member named 'elem' in 'arma::subview_elem2<double, arma::Mat<unsigned int>, arma::Mat<unsigned int> >'
  return D.cols(columns).elem(i);
         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ ^
1 error generated.
make: *** [file6cf4cef8267.o] Error 1
```

So, there is no way to *subset* a **subview** that was created by taking the a *subset* from an armadillo object.

---

You may want to read up on a few of the subsetting features of Armadillo. They are immensely helpful.

- Rcpp Gallery: http://gallery.rcpp.org/articles/armadillo-subsetting
- Guide to Converting R Code to Armadillo: http://thecoatlessprofessor.com/programming/common-operations-with-rcpparmadillo/
- Armadillo specific documentation

  - Matrix subsets: http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#submat
  - Individual entries: http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#element_access
  - `sub2ind()`: http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#sub2ind
  - `ind2sub()`: http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#ind2sub

**Disclaimer:** Both the first and second links I've contributed to or written.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation and the links - I've worked through several of them already, and will continue to do so.  I did check back and see that there were errors in my reproducible example (and fixed them - probably while you were working on all this).   Probably my best solution will be to figure out where the index is in the large data frame and grab it directly.  In any case, thanks!